# Конфликт одинаковых библиотек разных версий в .net

Tags: asp.net, c#, .net, библиотеки, asp.net-mvc

Имеется проект `Orchard CMS` (решение из 67 проектов). Внедрили в него свой проект на `ASP.NET MVC`. Наш проект использует библиотеку [`Castle`](http://www.castleproject.org/) 3.0, а `Orchard CMS` использует `Castle 1.1`. Обратной совместимости библиотеки не имеют (`CMS` использует методы и классы, которых нет в версии 3.0). Из-за конфликта библиотек, наш модуль не работает (выбрасывает `catch` с ошибкой загрузки библиотеки). Возможно ли решить эту проблему или хотя бы в каком направлении копать?
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Очевидное решение — переписать код под более новую библиотеку — не подходит? Всё лучше, чем городить костыли.

Comment: @vladD дело в том, что наш код использует новую библиотеку, а код CMS'ки - старые. Переписывать кучу кода внутри CMS - не лучшее решение

Comment: Хм, засада. Может, ну её, эту CMS? :-)

Comment: Можно попробовать разбить на 2 процесса — в одном CMS, в другом всё остальное. Ну или 2 `AppDomain`'а. Но это уже костыли.

Comment: Узнаю поганый почерк мелкософта - сочувствую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте `extern alias` для namespace'ов.

- [C# 2.0: Using different versions of the same dll in one application](https://web.archive.org/web/20160224135045/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/11/30/498278.aspx)
- [Extern alias walkthrough](https://web.archive.org/web/20160201161023/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Это делается через web.config (или app.config). 
У меня сделано вот так:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Core" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

PS ну и гуглите по слову assemblyBinding.

**UPD:** как верно подметили в комментарии, этот вариант будет работать только есть совместимость библиотек.

Comment: Не уверен, что это верное решение для описанной ситуации: автор использует библиотеку, которая завязана на старую версию Castle.Core (совместимости нет). Если вместо старой версии вдруг загрузится новая, библиотека перестанет работать.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, но решение подходит только если 2 бибилотеки не будут использоваться дискретно.